# How do some websites bypass the limits set on embedded YouTube videos by content creators?

Tags: javascript, video, youtube, google-api

I am working on embedding a YouTube video into a webpage using Google's embedded player JavaScript API, and some videos, such as any video from a VEVO channel, are not able to be played.

When embedded, the video does not play and shows this error message:
`This video contains content from VEVO. It is restricted from playback on certain sites or applications.`

How do some other websites, such as https://watch2gether.com, host these embedded videos with no problem?

Comment: Give link to an example page of such issue (make a temporary demo page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. The reason that the videos from YouTube were not playing was because I was accessing my website through the file system instead of using a hosted server. Any server will work, but I used Python 3's `http.server` module to host the website, and there were no problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

> *"I am working on embedding a YouTube video into a webpage"*

Is this not enough to display a Youtube video in your page? You must embed by I-Frame...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe 
width = 800;
height = 600;
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qFLhGq0060w"/>

</body>
</html>
```

PS: If your own website does not begin with `https://` then try testing the shown example link as `http://www.youtube.com/embed/qFLhGq0060w`.

Comment: I am embedding using the youtube iframe API, and for some reason some videos are not allowed to be played.

Comment: Give me an example link of such _" some videos are not allowed"_ for testing because all I see is **working** VEVO videos. The above code was tested and [**it displayed fine**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv3qi.jpg). Did it not work for you? What is your location (country)? If it worked for you then does it fix your _"such as any video from a VEVO channel, are not able to be played."_ concern?